# Oracle equiv of T-SQL UNION ALL query

Tags: oracle, t-sql

In T-SQL I can accumulate the results of two unioned queries using the following syntax:

```
SELECT Q.a, SUM(Q.b)
FROM (
SELECT f1 as a, f2 as b FROM TBL1
UNION ALL 
SELECT f1 as a, f2 as b FROM TBL2
)
GROUP BY Q.a
```

What is the equivalent in Oracle?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I get this super-helpful error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you alias the inline view to `Q`, that syntax should be perfectly valid in Oracle.  I'm assuming that you actually have the alias in the SQL Server version as well.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select q.a, sum(q.b)
  2    from (select deptno a, sal b from emp
  3          union all
  4          select 40, 10000 from dual
  5         ) q
  6*  group by q.a
SQL>
SQL> /

         A   SUM(Q.B)
---------- ----------
        30       9406
        20      10880
        40      10000
        10       8753
```

Comment: . . Ironically, the posted syntax should work for Oracle (which doesn't require aliases on subqueries), but shouldn't work in SQL Server (which does).

Comment: Absolutely right, it worked all along.  The actual statement was much longer, and in my final Group BY I had a space where a period should have been.  But you breaking it down helped.